# PATINDEX and CHARINDEX returning different answers SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a single table for which I wish to find all the instances where `0` is the **last** character in a string field.  I tried this by using two methods and they each returned different results.

This first query seemed to actually return the correct answer

```
select * from icd
    where CHARINDEX('0',icd,LEN(icd)) =LEN(icd)
```

this one does not catch all of the answers

```
select * from icd
    where PATINDEX('%0%',icd) = LEN(icd)
```

using

```
select t.ICD as theCharIndex,x.ICD as thePatIndex from
(

select * from icd
    where CHARINDEX('0',icd,LEN(icd)) =LEN(icd) 
) t
left join
(
select * from icd
    where PATINDEX('%0%',icd) = LEN(icd)
) x on x.ICD=t.ICD
where x.ICD is null
```

I found the set of data that `CHARINDEX` picked up that `PATINDEX` did not. I even did

```
update icd
set ICD=RTRIM(icd)
```

Why would `PATINDEX` indiscriminately leave out some rows?

Comment: It might be clearer to use `Right( icd, 1 ) = '0'`.

Comment: it ain't sexy, but it's certainly more concise :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have a 0 somewhere before the end. 
Change `PATINDEX('%0%',icd)` to `PATINDEX('%0',icd)`

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't `PATINDEX` return the FIRST "0" in the string and therefore if the string had more than one zero `PATINDEX('%0%',icd) = LEN(icd)` would be false even if there was another zero at the end??

Answer (score 1):

hard to say withou some data but I thiknk is that because you telling the CHARINDEX to start at the last position of the string, so it will only consider the last char (which seems what you want to do) but PATINDEX is lloking into all the string.

FYI, I think it would be better to achieve what you want with a SUBSTRING function

```
where SUBSTRING(icd, len(icd),1)
```